# How to get an Image by Xpath in HtmlUnit?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am trying to get an Image from an XPath in HtmlUnit, but the way I try it is not working for me.

Here is the Element I try to get:

```
<div id="image" style="width: 300px; height: 57px;"><img id="image_id" alt="Bild" height="57" width="300" src="snip"></div>
```

And here is my Code:

```
final List<?> divs = form.getByXPath("//div[@id='recaptcha_widget_div']//div[@id='recaptcha_image']");
HtmlImage img = (HtmlImage) imgs.get(0);
```

I know I cant cast a Division to a HtmlImage, but I dont know how to get the Image from the Division.

Comment: Also you can iterate over you div child elements. divs.get(0).getElementsByTagName("img");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element has a img tag. you should take its XPath with browser and use in HtmlUnit getFirstByXPath and put it in [HtmlImage](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlImage.html):

```
HtmlImage img = myPage.getFirstByXPath("//img[@id='image_id'])");
```

But if you have an element *id*, I recommend you using .getElementById(String id) method.